# Overloading operator() for a new struct

Tags: c++, struct, compare, overloading, operator-keyword

I defined a new `struct` in c:

```
typedef struct TypedObject {
    ObjectType type;
    void * value;
} TypedObject;
```

where ObjectType is an enum:

```
typedef enum ObjectType {
    type_node,
    type_int,
    type_error,
} ObjectType;
```

I would like to create a c++ set of `TypedObject` pointers and from previous questions I understood that I need to overload `operator()` in order to compare between `TypedObject` pointers inserted into the set.

Therefore I did it as follows:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
typedef struct {
    bool operator() (const TypedObject *lhs, const TypedObject *rhs){
        return (lhs->type==rhs->type) && (lhs->value==rhs->value);
    }
} ObjComparator;
#endif
```

Assume I define a set:

```
std::set<TypedObject *, ObjComparator> mySet;
```

You can assume that I use an iterator to iterate though the set.

I want to insert `TypedObject x` into the set. I use `mySet.insert(&x)` to insert its address.. but once I use `mySet.find(&x)`, it fails to find `x`. The call to `operator()` is made but the comparison is not made as expected.

Any idea what the problem might be with the way I overloaded `operator()`? what am I doing wrong?
Also, Should I overload a different version of operator like < or ==?

Answer (score 1):

The `Comparator` class you provide should implement an **order comparison**, so that `std::set` could use it to build a binary search tree.

That means that your `operator()` should not be symmetrical - by default it is a "less than" comparison.

In general, `operator()` of `Comparator` class should represent a strict order relation for your class, so it should be

- transitive - `C(a,b) && C(b,c)` means `C(a,c)`
- antisymmetrical - `C(a,b)` means `!C(b,a)`
- total - `!C(a,b) && !C(b,a)` means "a and b are equal"

The last definition of "equality" is what `std::set` uses when you call `set::find`.

**Solution:** While you surely can come up with some ordering that will satisfy the rules above, perhaps you can do with some refactoring instead.

If your `TypedObject`s have "address identity" (i.e. any object is only equal to itself), then you can just use the default comparison - it works perfectly for pointers:

```
std::set<TypedObject *> mySet;
```

If you need to compare the members after all, the usual approach would be something like this:

```
bool operator() (const TypedObject *lhs, const TypedObject *rhs)
{
    if(lhs->value < rhs->value) return true;
    if(rhs->value < lhs->value) return false;
    return (lhs->type < rhs->type)
}
```

Notice how it only falls back on `operator<` for members. In fact, it would probably be better to define `operator<` to compare `TypedObject`s, and then call it from the pointer `Comparator`.

Finally, if your `set` owns the objects (i.e. objects are destroyed upon leaving the set) then perhaps it's better to just use

```
std::set<TypedObject> mySet;
```

with the `operator<` overloaded for `TypedObject`. You will still be able to get pointers to objects from the set and use them in your C APIs, and you won't need to deal with extra comparator class and memory management.

Comment: Okay then. Should I compare the types and Addresses using the < operator?

Comment: @baronzo1 I've added my thoughts on possible solutions to the answer:)

Answer (score 0):

Your order comparison is wrong as based on equality it will not be able to create BST so correct code should be like below (note < in comparator)

```
typedef enum ObjectType {
    type_node,
    type_int,
    type_error,
} ObjectType; 

typedef struct {
    ObjectType type;
    void * value;
} TypedObject; 



typedef struct {
    bool operator() (const TypedObject *lhs, const TypedObject *rhs){
        return (lhs->type==rhs->type) && (lhs->value<rhs->value);
    }
} ObjComparator;

int main()
{
  std::set<TypedObject *, ObjComparator> mySet;
  TypedObject obj;
  obj.type=type_int;
  obj.value=(void*)new int;
  //*(obj.value)=4;
  auto insert  = mySet.insert(&obj);
  std::cout<<insert.second<<std::endl;
  if(mySet.find(&obj) == mySet.end())
  {
      std::cout<<"Not Found..."<<std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
      std::cout<<"Found..."<<std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't quite understand the changes u made in the `operator()` function. why should I check if the types are equal but when it comes to values I should see if one is less than the other?

Comment: ok how you will create BST, you need to compare element and then insert into left if it is less than and insert into right if it is greater than. so comparison can be done on equal type that's why type are equal but values are compared with less than

Comment: For the record, I am not dealing with BSTs here. I am working with a set of `TypedObject` pointers. 
But I get your point. Thanks =)

Comment: @Kapil but what if the types are not equal? the comparison will return `false` both ways then, which would imply that the objects are actually equal